# Ensuring VS 2008 is treating my project as C++ rather than C++/CLI

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, text-editor, keyword

I'm working in Visual Studio 2008 with native C++.

A colleague wrote a library, and he named one of his classes `interface`.  Here's a constructor:

```
template <typename DtedInterface>
interface<DtedInterface>::interface (
    std::string const& tleFile,
    std::string const& dtedDir,
    dted::DtedLevel const& dtedLevel,
    double sw_latitude,
    double sw_longitude,
    unsigned int rows,
    unsigned int columns )
    : m_impl ( new interface_impl<DtedInterface> ( theFile, dtedDir, dtedLevel, sw_latitude, sw_longitude, rows, columns ) )
  {}
```

What concerns me is that Visual Studio 2008 is highlighting the word `interface` as a keyword; `interface` is a keyword within C++/CLI but not C++.  This doesn't look like it would be valid C++/CLI, but it's fine for native C++.

Things look like they compile fine, but how do I make sure that Visual Studio is interpreting this as C++ rather than C++/CLI?  At *some* level, it appears that VS views this as C++/CLI.  Is it just a keyword highlighting setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Visual Studio IDE and the Visual C++ compiler are two separate entities. Specifically, they are two separate executables (`devenv.exe` for the IDE and `cl.exe` for the compiler) that run as separate processes. The IDE simply spawns the `cl.exe` process to perform the actual compilation.

The IDE has a list of keywords somewhere that simply tells the text editor which words to highlight. It isn't super sophisticated; it doesn't have to be. The compiler has the final say, not the syntax highlighter (or Intellisense for that matter).

As long as the [`/clr` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx) is not being passed to the `cl.exe` process, the compiler will compile the code as native C++ (which is the default setting). The IDE simply feeds in the file paths of your source code and the compiler switches as command-line arguments to the `cl.exe` process. The syntax highlighting has no bearing on how the compiler interprets the code.

Answer (score 3):

The code will refuse to compile if you're in C++/CLI, so as long as you push "build" and it works, then you know you're in native. There are also pre-defined macros for CLR builds.

Comment: I suspected that, but I know what happens when I assume. :)  Thanks for your response.

Comment: The code actually would not refuse to compile for CLR builds, because "interface" is not a keyword in C++/CLI when it appears by itself. It is only reserved if it appears as "interface class".

Answer (score 1):

If you're really need to verify it's not compiling managed C++, look at the project properties and check the "Common Language Runtime support" setting under the Configuration Properties->General. As well for each file's properties under Configuration Properties->C/C++->General check the "Compile with Common Language Runtime support" setting. If all of those are set to "No Common Language Runtime support", the project is not managed C++.